# Añadir Objeto String a Array de Strings

Tags: javascript, array

mi consulta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo añadír el nombre o el objeto tipo **string** a un **array** de **strings**?
Por ejemplo: Tengo un array de frutas,Melon, Piña y Manzana, después añadí Durazno y Naranja, pero resulta que tengo un objeto "Fruta" del cual, quiero crear un nuevo objeto y solo añadir el nombre de esa fruta al array.

El código no me da error pero me imprime lo siguiente:
**Melon,Piña,Manzana,Durazano,Canela,[object Object]**

Gracias! :D

```
var frutas=["Melon","Piña","Manzana"];

class fruta{
constructor(n){
this.nombre="n";
}
}


 function MostrarFrutas(){
document.writeln(frutas+"<br>")
//Este "for" es solo para que me imprima los indices del arreglo, no tiene 
//mayor función                  

    for(var e in frutas[0]){
        document.writeln("<br>"+e+"<br>");
    }
document.writeln("<br>");
 }
MostrarFrutas()
frutas.push("Durazno","Naranja");
frutas.push(new fruta("Kiwi"));
MostrarFrutas();
```

Comment: Puedo hacerte un ejemplo sin la clase? o ajuro tienes que tener la clase?

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo es agregar un objeto a un arreglo, pero recuerda que javascript no maneja tipado fuerte, así que tu arreglo en realidad no es de tipo string, pues puedes agregar números, fechas,y diferentes objetos o arreglos. En el caso de typescript si hubieras declarado `let arreglo: string[] = [];` para después hacer `this.arreglo.push(1);` te va a marcar error por que estas intentando agregar un dato numérico a un arreglo de tipo string.

Comment: de hecho el arreglo es un objeto con un comportamiento especial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres solo el nombre de la fruta puedes usar la propiedad `nombre` del objeto fruta

```js
var frutas=["Melon","Piña","Manzana"];

class fruta{
constructor(n){
this.nombre=n;
}
}

 function MostrarFrutas(){
document.writeln(frutas+"<br>")
 }
MostrarFrutas()
frutas.push("Durazno","Naranja");
frutas.push(new fruta("Kiwi").nombre);
MostrarFrutas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para añadirlo al final:

```
miArray = [...miArray, nuevoElemento];
```

Para añadirlo al principio:

```
miArray = [nuevoElemento, ...miArray];
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta lo que ya te han dicho: lo que tienes que agregar al array no es `new fruta("Kiwi")` sino `new fruta("Kiwi").name`